# Can I run a loop over multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, transform

so I want to replace the values within my columns, by replacing "Zero" to "0", "One" to "1" and "Two" to "2".
From:

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Two | Two | One |
| Zero | Two | One |
| One | One | One |

To:

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

However, I have many many columns that I need to do this with, so I try to write a function that can replace the values of one column (shown below), and make a for loop to repeat the same thing for multiple columns.

```
testfunction <- function(column){
    df <<- transform(df, column
                             = as.integer(as.character(
                                 factor(column, 
                                        levels = c("Zero", "One", "Two"),
                                        labels = c(0, 1, 2)
    ))))
}
```

The for loop:

```
a <- 1
for(i in 1:ncols(df)){
    a <- a + 1
    column <- colnames(df[a])
    testfunction(column)
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I assume I should have done it with a nested for loop in a cell by cell basis. But is there anyway you can do it by a column by column basis?

Thank you in advanced for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.integer(as.character(factor(., 
            levels = c("Zero", "One", "Two"),
                                    labels = c(0, 1, 2))))))
```

-output

```
#   V1 V2 V3
#1  2  2  1
#2  0  2  1
#3  1  1  1
```

---

Or this can be done in `base R` in a single line.  Also, can be extended to many more levels without having to write new lines of code

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) setNames(c(0, 1, 2), c("Zero", "One", "Two"))[x])
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("Two", "Zero", "One"), V2 = c("Two", "Two", 
"One"), V3 = c("One", "One", "One")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have only three numbers you can use indexing and finally formating as numeric values:

```
#Code
df[df=='Zero']<-0
df[df=='One']<-1
df[df=='Two']<-2
df <- as.data.frame(sapply(df, as.numeric))
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  2  2  1
2  0  2  1
3  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R option using `setNames`

```
df[] <- setNames(0:2, c("Zero", "One", "Two"))[unlist(df)]
```

such that

```
> df
  V1 V2 V3
1  2  2  1
2  0  2  1
3  1  1  1
```